# While running a hive action through oozie how can I fix the issue - "Unknown HS2 problem when communicating with Thrift server.?"

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, oozie, thrift

I am running two shell scripts and twelve hive actions as a data migration task. I am scheduling these using oozie. While I test the job as a dry run, the job sometimes executes partially and sometimes just a couple of hive actions are executed. After checking the yarn logs for the failed task - the following error is generated. Interestingly, different hive actions fail while performing successive dry runs and the error is the same as follows for all hive actions from the yarn logs:

Unknown HS2 problem when communicating with thrift server.
Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://******
javax.net.SSLHandshakeException
No current connection
Intercepting System.exit(2)
Failing oozie launcher, Main class exit code [2]

Every hive action has the jdbc hive uri specified.
Running the oozie job with a dedicated queue.
The hive-site.xml is part of the job.

The hive scripts run fine through the beeline and hue browser.

I am not authorized to upload the job.xml

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. This was due to two new nodes added to the cluster which did not have the same configurations as the previous. Came to this point since oozie jobs for other hadoop services also started reporting the same issue. 
Additionally the `yarn-logs` would provide you with the node the oozie job is running on and moreover it would fail at those same nodes. That's how kind of realized some issue with those nodes and interestingly those nodes were the newly added ones.